# Rails custom logger using concerns is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have a `logger_module.rb` file under `app/lib/concerns/` which look like this

```rb
module Concerns
  module LoggerModule

    def logger(text, logs)
      log_into_file(text, logs)
      log_into_kibana(text)
      # By calling his method, it will log into both Kibana and File
    end

    def log_into_kibana(text)
      tagged_logger ||= Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log")

      tagged_logger.info "[#{self.class}] #{text}"
    end

    def log_into_file(text, logs)
      logs << "#{text}"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using this Concerns to log anything into a file(which can be downloaded as `.log` file) and into Kibana(for tracking/searching log)

- Rails's `production.log` is mapped to Kibana so everything in `production.log` is shown in Kibana.

I'm using this logging method like this

```rb
class ActivateAccount
  include Concerns::LoggerModule

  def perform(logs)
    logger("Processing total of #{accounts.count} accounts", logs)
    # or
    log_into_kibana("Processing total of #{accounts.count} accounts")
    # or
    log_into_file("Processing total of #{accounts.count} accounts", logs)
  end
end
```

Noted that `logs` is an empty array coming from another RequestWorker class.

The problem I'm having is, it worked when I run it my local(I can see it in `development.log` and `production.log` if I do `Logger.new("log/production.log")`, but in production, nothing is being logged. Only the array `logs` is working.

Can someone help me please? I spent almost a month trying to figure this out.

Comment: Do you have any error in production? Did you try to run your app in production environment locally?

Comment: no, I don't have any error in production. If I do `logger = Logger.new(log/production.log)` and `logger.info "Log something"` then it will work. But it didn't work when put this logger into it own file.